# How to let user select a CRS in QGIS Python plugin?

Tags: pyqt, qt5, qgis, coordinate-systems, pyqgis

I am currently developing a QGIS Plugin in python. In it, the user should be able to select a Coordinate Reference System (CRS). In QGIS built-in dialogs, there often is this window called "Coordinate Reference System Selector" which allows selection of recently used CRS, as well as other Systems and also a Information box and visualisation of the Bbox of the CRS.

[image: CRS Selector]

Is there a way to replicate this? It would be very tideous to recreate all this informations and functionality. I would have excpected at least something CRS related in "QGIS custom widgets" in QT Designer, but I couldn't find anything.

Or if this isn't possible, is there at least a way to get all CRS's to display them in a Combobox?

Comment: Please forward a hello to S. Keller from me ;-)

Comment: @Thomas will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`QgsProjectionSelectionDialog`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/gui/QgsProjectionSelectionDialog.html):

```py
from qgis.gui import QgsProjectionSelectionDialog

dialog = QgsProjectionSelectionDialog()
dialog.exec_()

crs = dialog.crs()

print(crs)
```

There is also [`QgsProjectionSelectionWidget`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/gui/QgsProjectionSelectionWidget.html) if you want to embed it into your own dialog.